Energy balance - Cilynder of CO2

Hello, could some one support to solve this exercise?
Q = ∆U + W
Q = 0 (adiabatic - no heat Exchange with cylinder wall)
∆U + W = 0
m * cp * (t2 - t1) = - W (I'm stopped here)
Is this line of reasoning correct?
m = Is It the amount of CO2 in mols?
cp = 39,4 J/(mol * K)
t2 = the variable that I want to fins
t1 = 25°C = 298,15K
W = How calculate the work done?

Not in Portuguese I can't.  If you could get Google to translate the problem statement to English, you might have a better chance of getting help.

I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be in English.

I translated It to english, see If It is better

Now show your working so far so we may help you. We don't just solve problems aka do your homework.

I added some points at my post

Those are suggested answers down below?  I would think that since we are blowing down the CO2 from 10 bar to 1 to 8 bar, the temperature would go down.  Throttling is an isenthalpic process so if we find a point on the PH diagram for 25C and 10 Bar, and follow the enthalpy line down to 1 bar, we get a lower temp.  Looking at this (https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/thermophysics/Chart-p-h-CO2.pdf) diagram, I would expect the temp throttling from 10 bar to 1 bar to result in a gas at about 10C.
